how do I compile a vhdl file to be used in my work library
I have multiple files, one of which I want to use as a package for constants. Now I know that in theory I just have to compile all files into one work "library", but I always get the error message

unit "constant_package" not found in library work

for both my regular file, as well as my testbench.
My package looks like this :
library IEEE;
  use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
  
 
package constant_package is
-- defining a bunch of constants
end package constant_package;

and both my regular file as well as my testbench look like this :
library IEEE;
  -- 1 or more use ieee.,,,.all
  use work.constant_package.ALL;

-- rest of the file

my terminal inputs (I use a bash file for them) are:
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/path-to-package/Packages/
rm work-*.cf
cd /home/path-to-file/Component
rm work-*.cf
cd /home/path-to-testbench/Testbench
rm work-*.cf

cd /home/path-to-package/Packages/
ghdl -a constant_package.vhdl

cd /home/path-to-file/Component
ghdl -a file_name.vhdl


cd /home/path-to-testbench/Testbench
ghdl -a file_name_tb.vhdl
ghdl -e file_name_tb
ghdl -r file_name_tb --vcd=file_name.vcd --stop-time=100ns

and it does remove the old work__.cf file, compiles the package file and creates a new work__.cf file without a problem
I tried multiple combinations of terminal commands as well as saving package into the same directory of the normal file, all without much of a change

By default GHDL creates the libraries in the current directory. Compile everything from the same directory and things should be better: mkdir -p /tmp/build; cd /tmp/build; ghdl -a /home/path-to-package/Packages/constant_package.vhdl; ghdl -a /home/path-to-file/Component/file_name.vhdl...

@RenaudPacalet that did work so thank you, although I have seen this solution beforehand which is why I thought it would be possible to do it directly from different directories. Is that not possible at all to your knowledge, or did I just misunderstand something about it?

You can compile from different directories but then you must use the--work=NAME --workdir=DIR -PDIR1 -PDIR2... GHDL options to indicate the name and location of the target library, and where the various other libraries can be found. Note: I designed a dedicated Makefile for VHDL compilations and simulations with GHDL, Siemens Modelsim or Xilinx Vivado that you could be interested in: https://github.com/pacalet/mkvhdl.

The issue was that I created multiple work-__.cf files in  different folders by using
cd /home/path_to_package/constant_package.vhdl  

instead of just using
ghdl -a /home/path_to_package/constant_package.vhdl

which creates one work-__.cf file in which everything is compiled in
my followup question already got answered with the first comment, I just didnt realize it when I asked it
